# A picture and text in a table aren't on the same level

Tags: longtable, pspicture

Good afternoon

I have got one table (`longtable`). This table has many rows and three columns only. In 1st column is flag (picture, jpg) and other columns are some text. My problem is with the text - text isn't on the centre of the cell, picture below, but the text is downer.  How to fix it?

Thanks for help.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm,showframe]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

{\small
\begin{longtable}{l p{2cm}p{3cm}}
  \toprule
  \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{sk.png} & 
  Slovakia \textsl{[\textipa{sl@\textprimstress v\ae k.i.@}]} &      
  Bratislava\\
  \toprule  
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to adjust the image height with something like `\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-4pt}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{...}}`.  The `4pt` fine adjustment depends on the height of the content in columns 2 & 3 (which are top aligned).  Overall, I would propose this: `\begin{longtable}{l p{2cm}p{3cm}}
  \toprule
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height-4pt}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{sk.png}} & 
  Slovakia \textsl{[\textipa{sl@\textprimstress v\ae k.i.@}]} &      
  Bratislava\\[19pt]
  \toprule  
\end{longtable}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `includegraphics` puts the image on the base line. Asimple `\raisebox` will do:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=english,slovak]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mme]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

{\small\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{0.2pt}
\begin{longtable}{l p{2cm}p{3cm}}
  \toprule
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{sk.png}}} &
  Slovakia \textsl{[\textipa{sl@\textprimstress v\ae k.i.@}]} &
  Bratislava\\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]